# netplan not configuring network

Tags: ubuntu, networking, netplan

I'm trying to configure a static IP on a freshly installed, fleshly upgraded Ubuntu 20.04.03 system.

This is my `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
        dhcp4: no
        addresses: [192.168.178.91/24]
  version: 2
```

This is what I get from `ip a`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:10:c9:3f:8c:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

... plus lots of docker ifs.
```

When I

- run `netplan apply`,
- run `netplan generate ; netplan apply`
- run `netplan apply`, then reboot,

I don't get any errors, but `ip a` still gives me the same results and the system isn't reachable via the static address I'm trying to configure.
Also, the system is taking forever to start because it is waiting for dhcp.

When I introduce an error into the config file, netplan complains, so it's reading the right file.  When I run `netplan get`, the output is different from the config file, but equivalent:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.178.91/24
      dhcp4: false
  version: 2
```

**What am I doing wrong?**
**How can I check what netplan is doing, if anything?**

BTW: I don't think it's related, but when I run `netplan try`, I get "An error occurred: 'NetplanApply' object has no attribute 'state'".

I've seen others complain about that problem, but they were still able to `apply` their network configuration.

Comment: `try` should be executed `sudo  netplan try --state /etc/netplan`, did you get an error again? did you have other files under `/etc/netplan/`?

Comment: @GAD3R : Thank you, that solved the `try`-Problem.  I was sure a simple `sudo netplay try` used to work.

Comment: @GAD3R : And no, there's nothing else in `/etc/netplan`.